# MYSQL query 3 tables where match against

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a mysql query to match against a keyword. I successfully ran the query against a single table.

Code as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PART_DESC_TABLE 
WHERE MATCH (`DEEP_STD_SOCKET`,`DESCRIPTION_FB`,`DESCRIPTION_MKT`,`DESCRIPTION`,`DRIVE`,`POINT`,`SIZE`,`TOOL_CODE`) AGAINST ("12MM" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

I have two other tables that I need to include in above query, both (other two tables) have 3 columns where as this first table has 8 columns.

Few queries I have tried have failed so far. such as this one below:

```
SELECT
    TOOL_COMPANY_NAME,
    DEEP_STD_SOCKET,
    DESCRIPTION_FB,
    DESCRIPTION_MKT,
    DESCRIPTION,
    DRIVE,
    POINT,
    SIZE,
    TOOL_CODE,
    PART_NUMBER
FROM
    MANUFACTURERS,
    PART_DESC_TABLE,
    PART_NUMBER_TABLE
WHERE
    MATCH(
        `DEEP_STD_SOCKET`,
        `DESCRIPTION_FB`,
        `DESCRIPTION_MKT`,
        `DESCRIPTION`,
        `DRIVE`,
        `POINT`,
        `SIZE`,
        `TOOL_CODE`,
        `TOOL_COMPANY_NAME`,
        `PART_NUMBER`
    ) AGAINST('12MM' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

It results in

```
returns:  #1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH
```

Another query that i tried clearly stated that the number of columns was not even (Using UNION) which makes sense however evening setting some dummy values (i.e. NULL as column1,2,3....) still has not worked for me.

output to show select table

```
CREATE TABLE MANUFACTURERS ( MFG_NO int(3) DEFAULT NULL, ABBREVIATION varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, TOOL_COMPANY_NAME varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL, FULLTEXT KEY ABBREVIATION (ABBREVIATION,TOOL_COMPANY_NAME) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE PART_DESC_TABLE ( INDEX_NUMBER int(2) DEFAULT NULL, DESCRIPTION varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL, DESCRIPTION_FB varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, DESCRIPTION_MKT varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, DRIVE varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL, POINT varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL, DEEP_STD_SOCKET varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL, SIZE varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL, TOOL_CODE varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL, FULLTEXT KEY DEEP_STD_SOCKET (DEEP_STD_SOCKET,DESCRIPTION_FB,DESCRIPTION_MKT,DESCRIPTION,DRIVE,POINT,SIZE,TOOL_CODE) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 

CREATE TABLE PART_NUMBER_TABLE ( INDEX_NUMBER int(2) DEFAULT NULL, ABBREVIATION varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL, PART_NUMBER varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL, FULLTEXT KEY ABBREVIATION (ABBREVIATION,PART_NUMBER) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Also to further explain everything.

I have a part numbers table which basically can hold an indefinite number of part numbers. three columns. one is an index number and other is part number and third being manufacturers abbreviation (which will match to the manufactures table to get the full name of mfg. so basically aligning this data vertically i can have multiple part numbers with same index number which would basically belong to one item or row in part desc table.

next i have a part description table. i have an index number which should match index to the part number table with other columns that have item properties (e.g size, point, multiple descriptions)

last i have manufacturers table which has an mfg number, mfg abbreviation and then third is for mfg full name.

I am seeing suggestions for using joining condition rather than using match. I do also see issue of cross product for matching rows.

Can someone perhaps give me some guidance to how i can use join in this situation to achieve.

Comment: Do you have full-text indexes on `TOOL_COMPANY_NAME` and `PART_NUMBER`?

Comment: You don't have a `UNION`, so I don't see what your last paragraph has to do with this query.

Comment: Unrelated problem: you need a joining condition relating the 3 tables, otherwise you'll get a cross-product of all the matching rows.

Comment: Do you really need to look for `12MM` in the company name and part number? Maybe those columns are supposed to be the joining condition, not in the `MATCH()` condition.

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the 3 tables to the question?

Comment: Hello. thanks for the replies. Yes i do have full-text-indexes on all tables. I meant to say in last paragraph that i have attempted query with union however its saying uneven columns and when i use null as x to make dummy columns i still unable to run the query. I do have index numbers as the common factor between all three tables. basically trying to create a full text search system (php) using these three tables.

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Read my last comment.

Comment: PUT IT IN THE QUESTION!!!!